# Can I somehow show the Widget tree in a running app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I wonder, if a plugins exists, which allows to render instead of **Widget()**s just a rectangle and a **Widget()**'s name, to show the layout structure of the current view.

For debugging purposes.

**Does e.g. a plugin for this purpose exist?**

Comment: You can use [Dart DevTools](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-devtools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, just found the solution @quoci pointed out:

- Open Flutter Inspector
- Toggle select widget mode [small icon at the top]
- The open the app and click on a widget of the running application.

[image]